# Expectation of Compound Poisson process when N=0

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

I want to calculate the expected value of S that is the total damage.
S is the sum of single damages. $N$ is the total number of damages and it is also a RV that is distributed as a Poisson.
This seems like a Compound Poisson process to me except for the fact that I can't handle the case when $N=0$. 
I don't know ho to formally incorporate the case when $N=0$ in my calculation.
Do you see that from the third line on I only use the part where $S=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$? The part where the double summation starts results in the first case that has the internal summation that goes from 1 to 0.
This doesn't seem right to me 
Could you please help me to formally fix it?
thanks

[image: user formula]

Comment: In the very first line of the solution already stated that $S = 0$ when $N = 0$. And in the subsequent random sum the index is from $i = 1$ to $i = N$, for $N \geq 1$ case. So implicitly we have "dropped" the $N = 0$ case and you may think it is somehow an abuse of notation, but many will just accept this due to it is convenient and everyone can understand. You may also consider $E[S] = E[S|N > 0]\Pr\{N > 0\} + E[S|N=0]\Pr\{N = 0\}$ and then continue to do the double expectation.

Comment: ok thank you for the answer ...  basically what you have done is this:  $E[S] = E[E(S \mid N)]$ and you wrote de sigma lagebra generated by N as the union of two sets $A=\{N\mid N=0\} \cup B=\{N \mid N>0\}$. Then $E[E(S \mid N)] = E[E(S \mid A \cup B)]= ...$ here I don't know how to continue. Can you help me understand  how I can derive the formula you wrote?